# Lambda-based API Gateway POST endpoint unexpected response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I am developing a lambda deployment on an API Gateway. For that, I wrote this repository `https://github.com/trouchet/lambda-api`. It is just experimental, you can try with credential below:

```
{'api_key': '7Qnsu2Resua0UKopC1jpv922eE9jX7Vd9CmIYEKp',
 'api_url': 'https://76wtvuoioe.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/predict/',
 'method_verb': 'POST'}
```

To make deployment easy, I wrote this jupyter notebook file: https://github.com/trouchet/lambda-api/blob/main/deploy_notebook.ipynb. The code is below.

```
from requests import post

def query_post_endpoint(api_url_, api_key_, example_):
    headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/json', 
        'x-api-key': api_key_,
    }

    resp = post(api_url_, headers=headers, json=example_)

    # Check the response and handle it accordingly
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        response_data = resp.json()
        print(response_data)
    else:
        print("Request failed with status code:", resp.status_code)
        print(resp.text)

import json
import numpy as np

# Prepare the event to pass to the Lambda function
example=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

query_post_endpoint(api_url, api_key, example)
```

It works correctly:

`[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]`

My question: I had an idea to check for time response with code below.

```
import json
import requests
from about_time import about_time

# Prepare the event to pass to the Lambda function
example_sizes=[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 100000]
durations=[]

with about_time() as total_t:
    for example_size in example_sizes:
        with about_time() as single_t:
            # Transform into json format
            example=list(range(example_size))
            
            query_post_endpoint(api_url, api_key, example)
        
        durations.append(single_t.duration_human)
```

The final output is:

```
Request failed with status code: 502
{"message": "Internal server error"}
Request failed with status code: 502
{"message": "Internal server error"}
Request failed with status code: 502
{"message": "Internal server error"}
Request failed with status code: 502
{"message": "Internal server error"}
Request failed with status code: 502
{"message": "Internal server error"}
Request failed with status code: 502
{"message": "Internal server error"}
Request failed with status code: 502
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

Comment: Please look at the Lambda function's logs to see what the actual error message is.

Comment: Sure! I forgot about Cloudwatch

Comment: I clicked on my created lambda resource, but got many options available. I saw on tab these options: "Image", "Test", "Monitor", "Configuration", "Aliases", "Versions". I cannot find the proper place where logs lay

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html